# less to sass writing a very simple function

Tags: sass

I am switching from LESS to SASS  but have some difficulties to use it

very simple less variable + function Less :

```
 @mini :0.1rem;
 @brown:#533a38;
 .border(@color:@brown){border:@mini solid @color;}
```

I use it :

```
 #contact-form{
  .border();
}
```

how can I do the same with SASS ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mini :0.1rem;
 $brown:#533a38;
 @mixin border($color:$brown){border:$mini solid $color;}
```

Use mixin if you don't want to return anything. Now when we use border:

```
#contact-form{
  border: @include border;
}
```

Comment: No problem, just mark it as answer so that later others can verify their problems too. @ErickBoileau

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.